# How to verify text color in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, select, colors, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent

I have a web application.

Written automation script with selenium webdriver.

I have write some color code when I select some text.

> Now I want to check that color is present or not.

How can I verify color code in selenium webdriver script?

Comment: Try `String color = driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).getCssValue("color");`. I'm not sure that working for your case

Comment: Thanks but it is not working case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many try with different script finally I am able to find my question`s answer.

```
String colorString = driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).getAttribute("class");
String[] arrColor = colorString .split("#");
assertTrue(arrColor[1].equals("FFFFFF"));
```

Thank You all for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

```
WebElement eleSearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='navsearchbar']//div[2]//div"));

String rgbFormat = eleSearch.getCssValue("background-color");

System.out.println(rgbFormat);     //In RGB Format the value will be print => rgba(254, 189, 105, 1)

String hexcolor = Color.fromString(rgbFormat).asHex(); //converted Into HexFormat
System.out.println(hexcolor);// Output of Hex code will be  => #febd69
```

Answer (score 2):

Green color hash code #RRGGBB : **#008000** // Test Data, can replace with any specific color

Can try below code :

```
String colorString = driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).getAttribute("class");
String[] arrColor = colorString .split("#");
assertTrue(arrColor[1].equals("008000"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.getCssValue` to get the value of color.

As you specified, if you want to verify the color, you can assert it, something like this,

```
assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("css=td[bgcolor=#000]"));
```

Comment: Actually it has no CSS value. It is giving color after selection.

Comment: Is it a link text or what? please give more information

Comment: It is simple text. But now I want to check it`s colour code.

Comment: I will try your solution.If I get success to find it`s CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java class Color, because getCSSValue returns colour in RGBA.

```
Assertions.assertTrue(Color.fromString("#000000").equals(Color.fromString(yourWebelement.getCssValue("color"))), "Text 'fieldName' color");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can also try converting rgb into hex and verify...

// Color RGB   
 color = driver.findElement(By.id("xxxxx")).getCssValue("color").trim();    
 System.out.println("RGB_Color: " + color);  

 //  RGB to HEX   
 String color_hex[];  
 color_hex = color.replace("rgba(", "").split(",");       
 String actual_hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", Integer.parseInt(color_hex[0].trim()), Integer.parseInt(color_hex[1].trim()), Integer.parseInt(color_hex[2].trim()));  

// further can verify with Actual hex value with Expected hex value  
Assert.assertEquals("actual_hex should equal to: ", "#808080", actual_hex);
```